# Setting rotation axis as positive value

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an object. The object's initial rotation y axis is set to -90. I want to change the rotation to +90. I do it by following. However it changes to -90 degrees. Why does this happen and how do I make it positive at all times?
X=180, Y= -90, Z=180

```
void Start()
{
transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(transform.eulerAngles.x, -90 + 180, transform.eulerAngles.z);
}
```

Comment: int angle = -270;
            int results = (angle % 360 < 0) ? (angle % 360) + 360 : angle % 360;

Comment: Sounds like [an xy problem](https://xyproblem.info/). What are you trying to accomplish here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From the documentation:](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-eulerAngles.html)

> When using the .eulerAngles property to set a rotation, it is important to understand that although you are providing X, Y, and Z rotation values to describe your rotation, those values are not stored in the rotation. Instead, the X, Y & Z values are converted to the Quaternion's internal format.

Since several euler-angles describe the same rotation, there is no guarantee that you will get the same euler angles as you assigned. If you need this you may need to normalize the angles yourself.

My preference is to avoid euler angles as much as possible. In many cases you can use a vector and a up-direction to create a quaternion with the [LookRotation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.LookRotation.html). I find this easier since I have a much easier time to intuitively understand a direction-vector than an euler angle. Quaternions themselves are really hard to understand, but I find them fairly straightforward to use even if you do not understand the math behind them.

Answer (score 0):

While the angle is less than 0°, add 360°. Then while the angle is greater than or equal to 360°, subtract 360°.

If you are sure that the angle does not pass the range [-360°, 720°), you can trade the while's for if's.

Comment: so is there no way I can make my angle to positive 90 degrees?

Comment: @Roy: is my explanation so poor ??

Comment: no but honestly if you could explain it with the code it would be helpful.

Comment: @Roy: that *is* code !

Comment: Sorry but that did not work. I added currentAngle + 360 and the Y axis now is -270. Still in negative!

Comment: @roy - 270 + 360 = - 270. Your calculator is broken...

Comment: I know it should be 90 but it resets to -270. No other script is overriding this value.

Comment: @Roy: no, it does not "reset". Check your argument passing.

Comment: Now i have changed the initial rotation to -90. And I use this code: `transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(transform.eulerAngles.x, -90 + 180, transform.eulerAngles.z);` Technically it should be +90, but no, it changes to -90. Why?

Comment: My X and Z axis are 180. Is this the reason?

Comment: @Roy: check your argument passing.